# One line client-server calculator in C

Tags: c, linux, string, calculator

I'm trying to create a one line client-server calculator in C in linux and i'm stuck on something. I've already created a succesful communication between the client and the server and i know how to transmit data between them.
My problem lies in the string manipulation process. So the idea is that you run `./server PORTNUMBER` and `./client IP PORTNUMBER` . The code used for calculating the result lies on the server's side and everything else on the client's side. After executing both of these the user is asked to type a simple calculation like `10+5` or `4*9` etc. The server then calculates the result and it sents it back to the client for display.
I chose to approach this using string manipulation(that was my initial thought process).
Suppose the user types `10*51`. I save that to a string named `operation`. Then i do `if (strchr(operation,'*')) != NULL` to get in to the appropriate if statement. I create a variable `len1` to count all the characters until i meet * with `len1 = strlen(strchr(operation,'*'))`. I then `strncpy` this to a new string(with n = len1-1) and then use the `atoi` function to get the first operand. This seemed to be working fine at first for the first operand(i mean the number before the *). Then i decided to use `strrev` to turn `10*51` to `15*01` repeat the whole process and then use strrev again to turn `15` to `51` just before saving it as an `int`.
So my idea would look like this:

```
len1 = strlen(strchr(oper, '*'));
strncpy(operand1string,operation,len1-1);
op1 = atoi(operand1string);
strrev(oper);
len2 = strlen(strchr(oper,'*'));
strncpy(operand2string,operation,len2-1);
strrev(operand2string);
op1 = atoi(operand2string);
```

But for some reason this didn't work as expected. Am I on the right path here or should i implement it with another way? Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't write `'\0'` I think that might be the problem in your code. Also you should check for errors - `strchr(oper,'*')` may return `NULL`.

Comment: `len1 = strlen(strchr(operation,'*'))` will give you the number of characters from the `*` to the end of the string. It will not give you the number of characters from the start of the string to the `*`. If you want the number of characters from the start of the string to the `*`, you can use `strchr(operation,'*') - operation`.

Comment: If you just call `atoi` on the string `10*51`, it will return 10 because the `*` cannot be part of the number. Better yet, if you use `strtol(s, &end, 0)`, it will return 10 and place the address of the `*` in `end`, which will let you read the next number using `strtol(end+1, &end, 0)`. And you can just keep doing that; you're not limited to two numbers in the line.

Answer (score 2):

The statement `len1 = strlen(strchr(operation,'*'))` will give you the number of characters from the `*` to the end of the string. It will not give you the number of characters from the start of the string to the `*`. If you want the number of characters from the start of the string to the `*`, you can use `strchr(operation,'*') - operation`.

Also, I don't recommend using the function `strrev`, as it seems unnecessarily cumbersome to reverse the string twice.

In addition, as already pointed out by someone else in the comments section, the function `strncpy` will not write a terminating null character in your case.

Instead of relying on these functions, I believe the following approach would be better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum operation_type
{
    OPTYPE_ADDITION,
    OPTYPE_SUBTRACTION,
    OPTYPE_MULTIPLICATION,
    OPTYPE_DIVISION
};

struct operation
{
    enum operation_type type;
    long left; //left operand
    long right; //right operand
};

// On success, the function will return 0.
// On failure, it will return nonzero.
int parse_string( const char *input, struct operation *output )
{
    long left, right;
    enum operation_type type;
    const char *p = input;
    char *end;

    //attempt to convert the left operand
    left = strtol( p, &end, 10 );
    if ( p == end )
        return -1;
    p = end;

    //skip all whitespace
    while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        p++;

    //interpret operator
    switch ( *p )
    {
    case '+':
        type = OPTYPE_ADDITION;
        break;
    case '-':
        type = OPTYPE_SUBTRACTION;
        break;
    case '*':
        type = OPTYPE_MULTIPLICATION;
        break;
    case '/':
        type = OPTYPE_DIVISION;
        break;
    default:
        return -1;
    }

    //move pointer one past the operator
    p++;

    //attempt to convert the right operand
    errno = 0;
    right = strtol( p, &end, 10 );
    if ( p == end || errno == ERANGE )
        return -1;
    p = end;

    //make sure that the remainder of the string is either
    //empty or contains nothing except whitespace
    while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        p++;
    if ( *p != '\0' )
        return -1;

    //function was successful, so fill the output struct
    output->type = type;
    output->left = left;
    output->right = right;

    return 0;
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
int main( void )
{
    struct operation op;

    if ( parse_string( "20+30", &op ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "left operand: %ld\n", op.left );
        printf( "right operand: %ld\n", op.right );

        switch ( op.type )
        {
        case OPTYPE_ADDITION:
            printf( "operation type: addition\n" );
            printf( "result: %ld\n", op.left + op.right );
            break;
        case OPTYPE_SUBTRACTION:
            printf( "operation type: subtraction\n" );
            printf( "result: %ld\n", op.left - op.right );
            break;
        case OPTYPE_MULTIPLICATION:
            printf( "operation type: multiplication\n" );
            printf( "result: %ld\n", op.left * op.right );
            break;
        case OPTYPE_DIVISION:
            printf( "operation type: division\n" );
            printf( "result: %ld\n", op.left / op.right );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "operation type: unknown\n" );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "parse failure!\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In that case, it will print the following output:

```
left operand: 20
right operand: 30
operation type: addition
result: 50
```

As can be seen, the string has been correctly parsed, so that the result of the operation can be trivially calculated from the information written to the `struct operation`.